# Using css to only print hidden content

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am building a web app that needs to print a report when the user clicks a button. None of the content in the report is visible on the page, it only gets created when the user clicks the button. My initial idea was to simply open a new window, set the content, and then close the window after printing. However this is not an option because the users are using a browser in kiosk mode that is incapable of opening new tabs/windows. The requirement is that the report needs to print without redirecting from the current page. Only the report itself should be printed, none of the content from the current page can be included.

I understand that this has been posted here multiple times, but I have looked at a lot of those posts which is how I got as far as I am now.

When I click the button and print the page, it prints a blank page. I have no idea why this isn't working.

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
<html class="printable">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print-style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/report.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="printable">
    <div>
        <h1>Content that shouldn't print</h1>
        <h2>Content that shouldn't print</h2>
        <h3>Content that shouldn't print</h3>
        <h4>Content that shouldn't print</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="report" class="print-only"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
    :not(.printable) {
        display: none;
    }

    .print-only {
        display: block;
    }
}

.print-only {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#print-button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "get-report",
            success: function(resp) {
                $("#report").html(resp); // populate the report div with the response from the ajax call
                $("#report").children("*").addClass("printable"); // make all children of the report div printable
                window.print();
                $("#report").html("");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert the printable content into a hidden div and use the @media print to unhide it.

```css
.print {display:none;}

@media print {
  body :not(.both) {display:none;}
  .print  {display:block!important;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div>
    Screen content
  </div>
  
  <div class="both">Both media</div>
  
  <div class="print">
    Printable content
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Everything you insert into the print block will be in the printable version and nothing else. I added an example code, is the answer is what you looked for or am I missing something?

Comment: The only difference between your code and mine is that I'm black listing the content to hide when printing and you're white listing. This solution isn't working for me.

Comment: Well I guess I shouldn't say the only difference. My solution tries to allow for printing both `print-only` hidden content, and content marked as `printable`

Comment: This is not the only difference, you hide the printable version after the @media block and that is why you don't see it in the printable version. you get: display:block; ... display: none; and the latest win.

Comment: The problem is that the html and body elements need to be marked as printable as well. You cant just mark them as printable in the html because then the whole page is hidden when it loads, and you cant hide them in the `@media print` css block because then the entire page is hidden when printing.

Comment: But the html and body elements are just containers, you don't see them in the screen or the printable version (except bg). Run the code above, see the difference in the CSS order and the classes. I think it will solve your problems.

Comment: Just containers yes, but they must not be set to `display: none` otherwise none of their children will be shown

Comment: Of course :), Did you try my code include the html?

Comment: I did try your example and it does work. I guess I'm just hesitant to accept the whitelisting of adding the `screen` class to every element that shouldn't be shown in print. because my html file is a huge document with lots and lots of elements. I can't just use javascript to dynamically add `screen` to all elements without `print` because then I wouldn't be able to have elements in both print and screen, know what I'm saying?

Comment: If that is the problem just use the updated code above, You will only need to add `printable` and `both` classes.